# QGIS - 3.x Add overlay polygons ids to underlying lines that are 'within' or 'intersect'

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I am trying to add the 'id' of a polygon to the underlying lines that are 'inside' the polygon 'or' intersect the polygon.

For the underlying lines that are 'inside' polygon, I make a calculated field in the 'lines' layer as follows;

`array_first(overlay_within('polygons', 'id'))`

The above works fine, however, the above will only add 'id' to 'lines' that are totally 'inside' a polygon.  How can I add the 'or' logic and also how can I add lines that intersect the polygon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `overlay_within(layername)` as a boolean value and together with `CASE`it will be something like

```
Case
  when overlay_intersects('pol') then "id_intersects"
  when overlay_within('pol') then "id_within"
End
```

and there is one error in your expression, use "id" with double quotes instead of single quotes to adress a fieldname in QGIS expressions

Comment: Thank you.  I changed to Case
  when overlay_within('pol') then "id"
  when overlay_intersects('pol') then "id"
End // but it adds the id from the selected layer to new calculated field.  I would like to the id from the overlay.

Comment: It seems to me that overlay_intersects includes lines within AND lines that intersect.  Hard to see that in the documentation.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes this is correct, so you have to do the CASE expression in the right order, first intersects, then within. instead of "id" you can use your array_first(...) statement to get the id from the overlay...